# preg_match php parse html

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a problem to parse a html file using the php preg_match() function.

Here is a sample line of the html file:

```
<DIV STYLE="top:214px; left:506px; width:88px" Class="S7">15:03</DIV>
```

The div styles show a table that I want to read out. It is like a coordinate system. To get the content I need what is inside the div tag. But to know to what content the div belongs I need the top, left and width values. The div class is not always S7. And the content (here 15:03) can be either numbers 1234 (4 digits) times (00:00) oder letters (AAA).

I am new to regular expressions so my try might look very stupid to those who are familiar to them.

Here is what I tried. But did not get any result:

```
    $reg_ex = "/\<DIV STYLE\=\"top:([0-9])px; left:([0-9])px; width:([0-9])px\" Class\=\"S7\"\>(.*?)\<\/DIV\>/";
    $ret = preg_match($reg_ex,fgets($file),$outp);
```

Would be great if someone could help me.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$reg_ex = "/<DIV STYLE=\"top:([0-9]+)px; left:([0-9]+)px; width:([0-9]+)px\" Class=\"S7\"\>(.*?)<\/DIV>/";
$ret = preg_match($reg_ex,fgets($file),$outp);
```

`[0-9]` means exactly one char out of 0-9. However, you want to match one or more chars our ouf `[0-9]`, thus, you have to use `[0-9]+`

Also, you only need to mask special regexp-chars (i.e., "/") and not "<", "=", and ">" by prepending with a backslash. masking `"` is needed because you need to have double quotes within double quotes.

In my example the class is still hardcoded to `S7`. If you also need to parse it use `(.+)` instead (which matches any char and puts it into a group).